# Is there an image viewer which *won't* show every file in the current folder?

Tags: windows, images

Looking for a Windows image viewer which can be started from the command line but which allows me to specify/restrict which files I want it to page through. As parameters.

The good 'ol Windows Picture Viewer would be fine except that it'll show/cycle through all the pictures in the current folder.

In my case I want to say something like:

`someimgvwr.exe "cat.jpg" "cow.jpg" "cub.jpg"`

so that only those three files will be displayed and not "pig.jpg" which might also happen to be there in the same folder.

Actually, if it allowed something like this:

`someimgvwr.exe "c*.jpg"`

that would be even more perfect.

Do any of the many image viewers that are out there allow such a thing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IrfanView should be able to handle this.  Per the help file:

```
i_view32.exe c:\path\to\images /filepattern="*.jpg"
```

Comment: It does, I've checked that even not explicitly documented (or I had not found it) simply `i_view32 whatever*.jpg` works also (v.4.33; assuming exec in path and jpgs in current directory of course)

Comment: Nice!  So you don't even need the /filepattern switch?

Comment: AFAIK you don't but it's not documented so no warranties :-)

Answer (score 1):

If you type `kind:=Picture` in the Search box in Windows Explorer, you will see only images, which you can see if your view is set to thumbnails.

You can right-click on any image and select Preview to see the same images in Photo Viewer.

You can isolate any files with the appropriate search criterea, such as `"c*.jpg"`. Or, even better, `c* AND kind:=Picture` to isolate matching images of any type.

Comment: Good useful information. Can this be done from the command line? Do you know if this works with all versions of Windows? The question did not specify which version they are using. Also, this method includes results in sub-folders.